# ios12-Get set-cookie from NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: ios12

I got set-cookie in decidePolicyForNavigationResponse method before like this:

```oc
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler{
       NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)navigationResponse.response;
       self.response = response;
}
```

But in ios12 navigationResponse in this method cannot get set-cookie again.Can I have other method to replace it? Or is there any other method that I can get set-cookie on page? If you cannot understand please let me know. Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same issue as yours. I guess there is no longer retrieving cookies via `WKNavigationResponse`.  **(started from iOS 12.*)**

the cookies of WKWebview are stored in the `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()`

you could try to redesign the code as below instead of yours

**Objective-C**

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {  //available on iOS 11+
    WKHTTPCookieStore *cookieStore = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore;
        [cookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray* cookies) {
            if (cookies.count > 0) {
                for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
                    //TODO...
                }
            }
        }];
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
        for cookie in cookies {
              //TODO...   
        }
    })
}
```

Above codes are available on iOS 11+, if your app is supported for lower version
your should separate above code with yours.

hope it's works for you.

Comment: It works for me! But it have another question, I need the cookie in response instead the cookie on this wkwebview. Can I get that?

Comment: Have you met sometimes the completionHandler not go?

Comment: Why do you need it in the response?

Comment: Because the cookie in response is different form the cookie on this page

Comment: I didn't face this issue. I was able to use the same cookie from WKWebview as I was using it from navigation.response. If you are further using the cookie for your HTTPRequest then you need to save it in the HTTPCookieStorage using the below method
setCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie], for URL: URL?, mainDocumentURL: URL?)

Comment: @LydiaDai May I clarify your question? do you mean you would like to replace the cookies from http response? or you want to set cookies from http request?

Comment: @WeiGo I want to replace the cookies from http response.

Comment: @LydiaDai Actually you couldn't do this via http response. you could only retrieve the cookies in phase of `decidePolicyForNavigationResponse` before `didFinishNavigation`

Comment: you cannot hijack the cookies from http response to update as new one and then pretends the cookies as original which was sent by server to your WKWebview